# complex analysis explanation

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Can someone please explain why :

"Residue at a finite point is zero if the function is analytic at that point".

Some explanation going by the definition or Laurent's expansion will be helpful.

Comment: If the function is analytic at the point $z_0$ then the principal part of Laurent expansion near $z_0$ is equal to $0.$

Answer (score 2):

Here is the actual definition of a residue: Given a function $f$ which is holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood $\dot U(a)$, the *residue* of $f$ at $a$ is defined by
$${\rm res}(f|a):={1\over 2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_r} f(z)\ dz\ ,$$
where $\gamma_r:=\partial D_r(a)\subset U(a)$ is the boundary of a small disk $D_r(a)$ centered at $a$.

When $f$ is analytic in all of $D_R(a)$ for some $R>0$ then Cauchy's theorem guarantees that ${\rm res}(f|a)=0$.